# How can I get this mobile menu to look proper?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a client who has a lot of items in her menu:

shopshinelife.com

The theme we chose looks great on desktop, however 75% of her customers are on mobile, and the nav doesn’t perform well.

I limited the number of items currently in the mobile nav because #1 it’s hard to scroll (page content wants to scroll as well) and #2 the sub menu items are prelisted. I’d love to get them to dropdown when pressed, I just need some help with that code.

Here’s a simple structure of how extensive the menu is:

`Home
About
Products
-Best sellers
-Hot Deals
-Our Specialty
-Quick Ship
-A Gift For
--Her
--Him
--The Little One
-A Gift That
--Celebrates
--Encourages
--Renews
-Categories
--Apparel
--Bracelets
--Earrings
--Hand-stamped
--Keychains
--Necklaces
--Rings
-Collections
--Have Faith
--Monogram Madness
--Our Angels
--Personalized
--SHINE in the Home
--SHINE with F&C
--SHINE with Lisa Leonard
--This & That
Blog
FAQs
Contact
My Account
Checkout`

Thanks!
Nicco

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you tried? You can easily put all these items in a dropdown, but it sounds like you want to avoid the long list. Have you thought about a slide out menu with collapsible lists like this? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible/

Comment: Hello! I don't want to avoid the long list, I just want it Products to have it's items dropdown, and then each of it's items, items dropdown, but only one section open at a time so as to not have it all open at once. I supposed structured like the 'Mini' one in the link you sent.

Comment: This will get you started http://jsfiddle.net/zkngn0s7/ play around with the code

Comment: Really would help to see the actual code. Are you using this in a Panel? That could allow you to make a menu that does not take up screen space and does not scroll the page.

Comment: Hey Twisty. Would it not be easy for you to just 'inspect element' to see what's going on?

Comment: @NicolasHirajeta not really since this may or may not show me exactly what you're using. Also it's best to include the code that you have tried. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask